# How to create an indoor gardening?

Tags: vegetables, indoors, light

I'm looking to build an **indoor garden** to grow lettuce, basil, maybe tomatoes *etc*..

I have numerous questions :

- Are smart gardens a viable options ? (In terms of electricity cost and harvest quantity)
- If not, how to I build my setup ?
- Which lamp is the best in terms of quality of growth/low consumption
- and many more..

I've seen this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=710GLFRcEy4) but it doesn't explain anything about the lamp, how he built, which species he uses etc..

Do you know a website or YT video that teaches from scratch how to build one, which are the best lamps, how many light a day each plant need. I've seen much videos but they do not answer my questions above..
The main goal would be quality vegetables with low consumption lights. Is there any material that teaches from A to Z indoor gardening ?
Thanks !

Comment: If you look at the comments on the video you link to, someone has asked about the lights - Mr.Gardener answers saying they have made several other videos in regard to the  lighting... not sure where they are though, check his site. Also note the set up he's using is designed for cut and come again greens, in other words, they're always cutting the greens as they grow, not leaving them to mature as you would with, say, tomatoes.

Comment: yes I went on his website and I found nothing..
And yes that's why I want to start with lettuce and basil ;)

Comment: The only "smart gardens" are the "gardens with smart gardener". To answer, we must know much more data: where do you live? which use of your harvest? Why do you want it? (more sustainability, own vegetables). How much sun do you have in winter (this is the cheap option, the more sun you can get, the more easy and cheap it will be).

Answer (score 2):

In terms of low power consumption LED is the way to go, unfortunately it is also the most expensive one.

There are a lot of different brands offering all kinds of LED, just don't take the cheapest stuff you find on amazon.
If you settel for a mars hydro, make sure you visit their homepage before buying, sometimes you can get it cheaper there than on amazon.

For videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vleea-2n18
This is a video about which light to choose. The channel has a lot of other interesting videos as well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ-Hg_L011k&t=283s this one is about reflective materials

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2bw4cgkh9c&t=293s and this is some comparison video.

You will find lots of other videos in those channels.

Have fun and good luck

Answer (score 0):

Well besides the above mentioned, you can also create your own medical herbs corner where you can start growing herbs like chicory, calendula and so on. These plants don't require much sun and can easily be grown indoor.
In your case if partial sublight is available, you can grow the following herbs as well:

1. Feverfew
2. Chamomile
3. Marshmallow
4. Yarrow

These plants require at least 3 hours of sunlight to be available.
[Here](https://www.slideshare.net/ArturHarutyunyan13/the-medicinal-garden-kitpdf-261025113) is a good article that better describes these herbs, their health benefits, how they can be used and how can be grown.

Comment: Are you  associated with the site?  The plants mentioned will not grow indoors as the light levels are far too low

Comment: If you are associated with the site then you should read the help on "How not to be a spammer".  If you are not, then its best to declare that - this may stop some downvotes.